# Get middle value from a column name in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column name as `SAP_ID` whose value comes as `'I-JK-SGAR-ENB-H021'. SO I want` ENB` part from this column.

Below is the query:

```
select  SAP_ID, SITE_TYPE, SITEBACKHAUL, PRIORITY_SITE, RJ_COMPANY_CODE_1,  
BUSINESSRANKING, USAGE_TYPE, '1' AS STATUS
FROM R4G_OSP.ENODEB
 where SAP_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Apart from this being a duplicate, your requirements are unclear. Do you want the sub-string between the 3rd and 4th dashes or if the terms within the delimited string have fixed lengths do you simply want the sub-string consisting of the 11th - 13th characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two usual options: regular expression or substr + instr combination.

Regular expression extracts 4th *word* from that string.

Substr + instr combination extracts string between 3rd and 4th `-` character.

```
SQL> with enodeb (sap_id) as
  2    (select 'I-JK-SGAR-ENB-H021' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(sap_id, '\w+', 1, 4) result_1,
  4         --
  5         substr(sap_id, instr(sap_id, '-', 1, 3) + 1,
  6                        instr(sap_id, '-', 1, 4) - instr(sap_id, '-', 1, 3) - 1
  7               ) result_2
  8  from enodeb;

RESULT_1   RESULT_2
---------- ----------
ENB        ENB

SQL>
```

---

As of *usage type*: use `case` expression, e.g.

```
select case regexp_substr(sap_id, '\w+', 1, 4)
            when 'ENB' then 42
            when 'COW' then 44
       end as usage_type
from ...
```

Comment: One more thing if value is `ENB` then I want to set usagetype as 42, and if value is `COW` then i want to set usage type as 44